# Suboptimal Memory Handling in Large-Scale Library Application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, security, schedule

I'm facing an issue with my current implementation involving the following line:

```
List<AppUserEmailBooks> appUserEmailBooksList = new ArrayList<>();
```

This approach seems to be suboptimal for the following reasons:

Memory Usage: Storing everything in memory is problematic, especially considering that this application is intended for a public library where there could be tens or even hundreds of millions of users.

Search Performance: Searching for a user each time I want to add books to their list will become increasingly time-consuming as the number of users served by the application grows. In practice, this process could take several days, even on a standard computer, or possibly even longer.

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class EmailSchedule {


    private final EmailService emailService;

    private final BookRepository bookRepository;

    private final SubscriptionRepository subscriptionRepository;

    @Scheduled(cron = "${scheduled.email.notification.cron}")
    public void sendScheduledEmailNotification() {
        LocalDate todayDateTime = LocalDate.now();
        final int pageSize = 10000;
        Page<Book> pageResult;
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, pageSize);

        List<AppUserEmailBooks> appUserEmailBooksList = new ArrayList<>();

        do {
            pageResult = bookRepository.findAllByAddedDateToday(todayDateTime, pageable);
            List<Book> newBooks = pageResult.getContent();

            processSubscriptionsInBatches(newBooks, appUserEmailBooksList);

            pageable = pageResult.nextPageable();
        } while (pageResult.hasNext());

        for (AppUserEmailBooks appUserEmailBooks : appUserEmailBooksList) {
            String userEmail = appUserEmailBooks.getUserEmail();
            List<Book> matchedBooks = appUserEmailBooks.getMatchedBooks();
            emailService.sendNotificationIfNewBooks(userEmail, new ArrayList<>(matchedBooks));
        }
    }

    public void processSubscriptionsInBatches(List<Book> newBooks, List<AppUserEmailBooks> appUserEmailBooksList) {
        int batchSize = 100;
        int page = 0;

        Pageable subscriptionPageable = PageRequest.of(page, batchSize);
        Page<Subscription> subscriptionPage;

        do {
            subscriptionPage = subscriptionRepository.findAll(subscriptionPageable);
            List<Subscription> subscriptions = subscriptionPage.getContent();

            for (Subscription subscription : subscriptions) {
                Set<Book> matchedBooks = matchBooksToSubscription(subscription, newBooks);

                if (!matchedBooks.isEmpty()) {
                    String userEmail = subscription.getAppUser().getEmail();
                    updateUserEmailBooksList(userEmail, matchedBooks, appUserEmailBooksList);
                }
            }

            subscriptionPageable = subscriptionPage.nextPageable();
            page++;
        } while (subscriptionPage.hasNext());
    }

    public void updateUserEmailBooksList(String userEmail, Set<Book> matchedBooks, List<AppUserEmailBooks> appUserEmailBooksList) {
        for (AppUserEmailBooks appUserEmailBooks : appUserEmailBooksList) {
            if (appUserEmailBooks.getUserEmail().equals(userEmail)) {
                appUserEmailBooks.getMatchedBooks().addAll(matchedBooks);
                return;
            }
        }
        appUserEmailBooksList.add(new AppUserEmailBooks(userEmail, new ArrayList<>(matchedBooks)));
    }

    public Set<Book> matchBooksToSubscription(Subscription subscription, List<Book> newBooks) {
        Set<Book> matchedBooks = new HashSet<>();
        for (Book book : newBooks) {
            if (book.getAuthor().equals(subscription.getBookAuthor()) ||
                    book.getCategory().equals(subscription.getBookCategory())) {
                matchedBooks.add(book);
            }
        }
        return matchedBooks;
    }
}
```

```
@Service
public class EmailService {

    private final JavaMailSender mailSender;

    @Value("${library.base-url}")
    private String baseUrl;

    public EmailService(JavaMailSender mailSender, @Value("${library.base-url}") String baseUrl) {
        this.mailSender = mailSender;
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
    }

    public void sendConfirmationEmail(String to, String subject, String token) {

        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setTo(to);
        message.setSubject(subject);

        String link = baseUrl + "?token=" + token;

        StringBuilder messageContent = new StringBuilder("<p>Thank you for registering, please confirm your email address!</p>\n" +
                "<p>Click the button to confirm:</p>" + link);

        message.setText(String.valueOf(messageContent));
        mailSender.send(message);

    }


    public void sendSimpleMessage(String to, String subject, String text) {

        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setTo(to.trim());
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(text);
        mailSender.send(message);
    }

    public void sendNotificationIfNewBooks(String to, List<Book> books) {

        String subject = "New books added to the book store!";

        StringBuilder textBuilder = new StringBuilder("New books added to the store, take a look at the new positions below! :\n");
        for (Book book : books) {
            textBuilder.append("Title: ").append(book.getTitle())
                    .append(" Author: ").append(book.getAuthor())
                    .append(" Category: ").append(book.getCategory())
                    .append("\n\n");

        }

        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setTo(to);
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(textBuilder.toString());

        mailSender.send(message);

    }
}
```

```
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT b FROM Book b WHERE b.addedDate = CURRENT_DATE")
    Page<Book> findAllByAddedDateToday(LocalDate addedDate, Pageable pageable);
```

```
@Repository
public interface AppUserRepository extends JpaRepository<AppUser, Long> {

    @Lock(LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC)
    Optional<AppUser> findAppUserByConfirmationToken(@Param("confirmationToken") String token);

    @Lock(LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC)
    @Query("SELECT v FROM AppUser v WHERE v.id = :id")
    Optional<AppUser> findByIdForLock(Long id);
}
```

```
public interface SubscriptionRepository extends JpaRepository<Subscription, Long> {

    @Lock(LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC)
    boolean existsByAppUserIdAndBookCategory(Long appUserId, String category);

    @Lock(LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC)
    boolean existsByAppUserIdAndBookAuthor(Long appUserId, String author);
}
```

I have already tried using Map's although it's even more memory consuming especially on large scale.

I'm seeking advice on how to improve this situation. Any suggestions on alternative approaches or best practices for handling large-scale data in a memory-efficient and performance-conscious manner would be greatly appreciated.

The program is to fulfill the need for a library, which is looking to add books & register users and subscriptions. If the user is subscribed to a category or author or both, an email should be sent once per day notifying the user about a new book. There shouldn't be any duplicates sent if the user is subscribed to a category as well as author.

Comment: Are you claiming that searching for a user could take *several days*?

Comment: ~Yes, with time as the number of users would increase it would be more memory consuming & the search would take longer.

Comment: Longer, sure; where do you get *several days* from?

Comment: I guess if the db is in the millions it would take much longer than that. So I'm looking for something that would be more optimal.

Comment: Possibly would Spring Batch be a good option to limit the entries which are being added into the memory?

Comment: Where's your "find a user" query? Finding a user by username in a database with even a billion users should be almost "instant" if you've structured your database correctly with correct indexes, etc. and have appropriate hardware.

Comment: @SledgeHammer

So what I would be doing is searching for books that would be added within 24h & then pulling in the subscriptions that have been created on the category or author & then searching for the user. 

Then the schedule would keep it in memory & send batch of emails with all of the books that the user is subscribed to. 


Allows me to not re-send emails to the same user etc.

Ive added my repository for book / subscription / appuser

Comment: You shouldn't do one piece of the query at a time as you have shown above. Create a query with joins that joins all those tables on the appropriate PK or indexed column with the appropriate filters that are indexed as well. Also don't use Pageable it will not scale well. Use keyset pagination instead.

Comment: @SledgeHammer Ive managed to come up with something on the lines of:  
                                 
@Query("SELECT u, b " +
       "FROM Book b " +
       "JOIN Subscription s ON b.author = s.bookAuthor OR b.category = s.bookCategory " +
       "JOIN AppUser u ON s.appUser.id = u.id " +
       "WHERE b.addedDate = CURRENT_DATE")
Set<AppUser> findUsersWithBooksAddedToday();

You recon it should do the job?